# ZXing running (crashes...) on iPod

Tags: ios, xcode, qr-code, ipod, sigabrt

I got a really weird problem with ZXing 2.0 on iPod touch (Version : 5.1.1).
I searched on the Internet and Stackoverflow but i think i just ignore the origin of that issue so i couldn't find anything.
I coded an app which successfully using ZXing running on iPhone Simulator 5.1 and when i try to run on any iPod device (i didn't test other device yet), it compiles and crash at running with no log in console (and i cant type anything on it).

This is the screen that appeared on XCode (i got the developer version 4.3.2) with a green arrow for the last line pasted and "signal SIGABRT" written.

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib __pthread_kill:
0x35e70324:  mov    r12, #328
0x35e70328:  svc    #128
0x35e7032c:  blo    0x35e70344; __pthread_kill + 32 (arrow for this line)
```

I think it's related to the libZXingWidget.a static library and I configured the build settings for armv6 armv7 and i386 in two different configurations but didn't work either.

I have no idea anymore, thanks for any suggestion !

**EDIT** : I forgot to mention that the next thing on the thread stack is `GSRegisterPurpleNamedPort`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rebooting the device. Coring in `GSRegisterPurpleNamedPort` is pretty common under certain conditions, for example switching between a debug version and an archived ipa. In that case, it's a Mach thing and seems to require a reboot. From what you've said, it doesn't sound like the issue, but it's worth ruling out.

Otherwise:

1. Have you run any app on your device, i.e., is everything properly provisioned?
2. Can you get `ScanTest` to run on your device?
3. Post the whole stacktrace.

Comment: First, thanks for your time, my last app ran perfectly on this device. I tried to reboot before asking here but when i did it this morning it solved my problem and everything's ok, thanks again.